# How to get sum of associated model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

```
class AssessmentScore < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :exam_group
  belongs_to :ca_criteria
end

class CaCriteria < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :assessment_scores
  belongs_to :ca_group

  validates_numericality_of :max_marks
end
```

I tried running the following code fragment:

```
ca_scores = {}
AssessmentScore.find(:all,
  :conditions=>["exam_id IN (1,2,3) AND ca_criteria_id IS NOT NULL"],
  :include=>:ca_criteria
).group_by(&:exam_id).each do |e_id, v|
  ca_scores[e_id] = {}
  v.group_by(&:student_id).each{|s_id, v2|
    ca_scores[e_id][s_id] = {:score=>v2.sum(&:grade_points), :max_marks=>v2.ca_criteria.sum(&:max_marks)}
  }
end
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in reportsController#create_reports
>
> undefined method`ca_criteria'

This is how I got it working:

```
  ca_scores = {}
  AssessmentScore.find(:all,
    :conditions=>["exam_id IN (1,2,3) AND ca_criteria_id IS NOT NULL"],
    :include=>:ca_criteria
  ).group_by(&:exam_id).each do |e_id, v|
    ca_scores[e_id] = {}
    max_marks = 0
    v.group_by(&:student_id).each{|s_id, v2|
      v2.each{|v3|
        max_marks += v3.ca_criteria['max_marks']
      }
      ca_scores[e_id][s_id] = {:score=>v2.sum(&:grade_points), :max_marks=>max_marks}
    }
  end
```

I'm curious, whats the error free way of writing the code below:

```
:max_marks=>v2.ca_criteria.sum(&:max_marks)
```

Comment: I think you can easily debug and find the problem, `v2` obviously is an array of `AssessmentScore`, so you can not call `ca_criteria`.

Comment: Curious syntax, I should note... All this in one single command will be hell to debug... I agree with @BlueSmith 's comment though.